# ReSharper - Document Saved Event For Inactive File in Visual Studio

Tags: resharper, vsix

I’ve set up my own source control plug-in for Visual Studio.

It’s registered with visual studio and can be selected from the list of Source Control plug-ins.

I’ve got no issues with files that are modified from with in Visual Studio as I’m using to catch the event before save:
**IVsRunningDocTableEvents3**

If the file isn’t loaded as an active document in Visual Studio, I’m having problems detecting that it is about to be edited so I can check it out of Source Control.

I’ve tried using the ReSharper event – DocumentManagerOperations suggested here:

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205991489-Document-Saved-Event

I’m having issues detecting if these types of files need checked out:

- .DotSettings. – When saving the ReSharper options settings
- csproj – When adding Nuget Packages with ReSharper.
- .cs when editing files that are not opened in VS with ReSharper, i.e.
  fix naming in project.

Is there an event that’s triggered when a file is edited but not loaded?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used the interface:
IVsQueryEditQuerySave2

More information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsqueryeditquerysave2?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

And made use of:

```
public int QueryEditFiles(uint rgfQueryEdit, int cFiles, string[] rgpszMkDocuments, uint[] rgrgf,
        VSQEQS_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA[] rgFileInfo, out uint pfEditVerdict, out uint prgfMoreInfo)
```

And:

```
public int QuerySaveFiles(uint rgfQuerySave, int cFiles, string[] rgpszMkDocuments, uint[] rgrgf,
        VSQEQS_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA[] rgFileInfo, out uint pdwQsResult)
```

something like this:

```
if (rgfQueryEdit != (uint)tagVSQueryEditFlags.QEF_ReportOnly)
        {
            if (rgpszMkDocuments != null)
            {
                foreach (var doc in rgpszMkDocuments)
                {
                    //Do Something
```

Hope that helps you out.